# findBy with custom filter in PagingAndSortingRepository

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have an interface extending the [PagingAndSortingRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html)

I have a custom find like :

```
findJobByNameBySystemIdUserCompanyId(companyId, pageable)
```

This works fine, now I want to introduce filtering, so I want to search (like) for string in the list.

How can I achieve that? The search term could be on any field ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please have a look here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

example: findByFirstnameLike(...), findByFirstnameNotLike(...)

Comment: I think if you need to have dynamic filter, - you would need to create your own implementation basedn on lower level abstractions (ex. Query and Criteria )

Comment: The only problem I see with the above option is that the like will be for firstname not for all the other fields/tables hence I think I am going to have to implement something on my own!

Comment: yes, Like goes for particular field, another Like for another field. In case of 1 Like -> Many Field, only custom implementation.... But even so with Spring data it's very easy.

Comment: is there any documentation on that?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations